# How to make a 1:1 relation between dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a table about **occupational accidents** in a Company. This table have a date column about when this accidents happened. What I want to do is make another table about occupational accidents dates with day, month and year columns which is joined with the another table by the date I extracted from the Occupational accidents table (In my database known as OPS table.

I thought it would be easy but when i tried to do the relationship beetween OPS[Fecha](This is the field date from OPS table) and Date[ID](Date is how i called my new table and ID is the field joined with the another table), the relationship returns me as **many to many** what makes no sense because i think it should be 1 to 1.

**This is what i did and my result:**

1.This is the table I'm talking about.

[image: OPS Table]

2. I added as a new query:

[image: Fecha]

3. Convert to table.

[image: Table Fecha]

4. I changed the column name to ID

[image: column name]

5.Then I try to make the relationship between these 2 tables waiting to get a 1 to 1 relation and I get this:

[image: Problem]

**What I want to get is something like this relation:**

[image: solution]

Comment: Some date and time values are repeated in the table and that is why the relationship is Many-to-Many. I can't say anything about One-to-One but One-to-Many is possible if the new query table uses distinct date and time to filter out duplicates.

Comment: I advice you to learn a bit more on Power-BI dates. The table you want to create your month, day, etc. is out of the box. Dates create this heirarchy by default.

Comment: I'm using a direct query with my database that's why the heirarchy doesn't appear

Comment: @NoeliaSanchoMendez Do you need so much granularity in your date field i.e. do you need the time value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new query and after converting it to a table, add a new step to **remove duplicates**(screenshot below). Once this is done you will be able to create a **One-to-Many** relationship between these 2 queries. But you **CAN'T** be able to create **One-to-One**.

[image: remove duplicates]

Also, please search online on how relationships work in Power BI. I recommend this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4ybWQSRcOY